# is there a way to combine lists without copying the content?

Tags: python, list

I basically want to combine the references to the two lists in a way that doesn't copy the content.

for example:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

combined_list = combine(list1, list2)
# combined_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

list1.append(3)
# combined_list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: What is the logic by which 3 ends up being inserted in the middle?  Do you want a sorted list?

Comment: You just seem to want to combine the references of the two lists.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it sounds like they want a sort of overlaying view of the two lists. Appending to `list1` causes the "view" to reflect the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to `collections.ChainMap` to implement a `ChainSeq`. Here is a print only version:

```
from itertools import chain


class ChainSeq:
    def __init__(self, *seqs):
        self.seqs = list(seqs) if lists else [[]]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{", ".join(map(repr, chain.from_iterable(self.seqs)))}]'
```

Test:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> combined_list = ChainSeq(list1, list2)
>>> combined_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list1.append(3)
>>> combined_list
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

simlpicity is important in python
you can use extend method

```py
lst1 = [1, 2, 3]
lst2 = [4, 5, 6]
lst = []
lst.extend(lst1)
lst_extend(lst2)
```

Comment: This does not address the question. The goal is to make it so that, if `lst1` is modified *afterward*, the combined result *reflects that change*.